# If A and B are any two subsets of the set $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$, how do we determine the number of times where A and B don't intersect?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

For the set where $n = 2$ I was able to determine that there are $9$ possibilities where two subsets $A$ and $B$ don't intersect.

These are:

$A= \emptyset, B = \emptyset$

$A= \{1\}, B = \emptyset$

$A = \emptyset, B = \{1\}$

$A = \{1\}, B = \{2\}$

$A = \{2\}, B = \{1\}$

$A = \{2\}, B = \emptyset$

$A = \emptyset, B = \{2\}$

$A = \{1,2\}, B = \emptyset$

$A = \emptyset, B = \{1,2\}$

How do I determine the number for the set with $n$ elements?

**Edit:**

I initially missed the case where both subsets are empty thus, there are $9$ possibilities.

Comment: Are you asking for the number of ways of selecting two disjoint subsets of a set with $n$ elements?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And the set with n elements is just the set of natural numbers from 1 until n.

Comment: By the way, you omitted the case $A = B = \emptyset$.

Comment: So that would make them 9 possibilities?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: N. F. Taussig, thanks I will try to edit the post with this in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your sets are labeled, $A = \{1\}, B = \{2\}$ is different from $A = \{2\}, B = \{1\}$.  In your example, you omitted the case $A = B = \emptyset$.  Hence, you should have nine ways of selecting two labeled disjoint subsets of the set $\{1, 2\}$.

For each of the $n$ elements in the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$, you have three choices: place the element in set $A$, place the element in set $B$, or place the element in neither set.  Therefore, the number of ways of selecting two labeled disjoint sets of the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$ is ...?

Comment: For $n= $2 it was $3^2$ so it must be $3^n$?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 3):

In general  A , B $\subset \{1,2,3,...,n\}$ and A $\cap$ B =$\phi$

Suppose if $|A|=k $ and $|B|=n-k$ then possible ways

for A  are $n\choose k$ and for B are $2^{n-k}$ where $k=0,1,2,...n$

Hence total number of ways are $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} 2^{n-k}=3^n$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please elaborate on how we came up with $2^(n-k)$ possibilities for $B$ ?

Comment: We took k elements in set A  now B have at most n-k element and number of such subsets are 2^(n-k) which is a basic formula (Number of subsets of set with n elements are 2^n)